# Integration question

Tags: calculus, integration

Show that the substitution $u=e^x$ converts $\int \frac{2+\ln(u)}{u^2} du$ into $\int \frac{2+x}{e^x} dx$Hence evaluate $\int_1^e \frac{2+\ln(u)}{u^2} du$I have tried every substitution available and still cannot come to an answer. I can find the answer via integration by parts but not through a substitution which I think is required.
Thanks

I don't think I'm supposed to use parts

Comment: What is your problem? The substitution $u=e^x$  is given, so $\ln(u)=x$ and $du = u dx$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**
$$\int \frac{2+\ln(u)}{u^2}{du}$$
Now, Substitute $ u = e^x, \space du = e^xdx$
$$I = \int \frac{2+\ln e^x}{e^{2x}} e^x \, dx$$
$$I = \int \frac{2+x}{e^{2x}}e^x\,dx = \int \frac 2{e^x} \,dx + \int \frac x{e^x} \,dx$$
$$I = I_1 + I_2$$
Now you solve $I_1$ by simply integrating it and apply integration by parts in $I_2$. After that substitute back $ x = \ln(u)$ in the result.

Answer (score 0):

Write your integrand as (2+x) Exp[-x]. Develop. Then, you have to integrate Exp[-x] + x Exp[-x]. The first one is simple. For the second, use integration by parts.

Answer (score 0):

$$u = e^x\\
du = e^x dx\\
\int \frac{2+\ln(u)}{u^2} du= \int \frac{2+x}{e^{2x}} e^xdx= \int \frac{2+x}{e^x} dx\\ $$